# Parsing array from javascript to ruby on rails but getting it as string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So im getting an array from parameters(JS)

```
"[[\"01000290056001\",0],[\"01000290056002\",0]]"
```

The problem is in quotes that are at the start and at the end, ruby reads this not as array but as string.

Here is the screenshot with parametres that I get from JS (http://prntscr.com/p8fagj)

JS that is used

```
$('.button').bind("click", function() {
        var ar_id = $(this).attr("testval");
        collectID = $('input[checked]:not(:checked), input:not([checked]):checked')
            .map( ( _, it ) => [[ it.value, it.checked ? 1 : 0 ]] )
            .get()

        $.get('/places/call_this',
            {
                cad_ids: JSON.stringify(collectID),
                ar_id: ar_id

            },
            function(response) {
                // nothing here
            }
        );
    })
```

The question is how to correctly pass the array to Ruby Controller without quotes? Or how to remove them in the controller directly?

So in the end, I need something like this

```
[["01000290056001",0],["01000290056002",0]]
```

It will be used for `.each` function.

Comment: Typically you should not pass json as a get parameter, but in the body either on it's own, or as part of a post query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse):

```
require 'json'

response = "[[\"01000290056001\",0],[\"01000290056002\",0]]"
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
# => [["01000290056001", 0], ["01000290056002", 0]]

parsed_response.each do |item| 
  # whatever you want
end
```

That will convert your response into a Ruby array for you to use. Let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It worked. Have tried it before and were unlucky :(.

Comment: Great, glad it helped @Marshmello - if you're satisfied it answered the question please feel free to give it a tick confirming that :)

Comment: Sure! Then you one more time :)